# Why is my recursion not running with variables?

Tags: c, recursion, return-value, function-definition

I wanted to ask why the first code functions and the second is not? Both are recursions and should calculate the binomial coefficient when going up the pascal triangel. Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int rekurs(int n, int k)
{   if((k==0)||(n==0)||(n==k))
    {
        return 1;
    }

    else{ 
      return rekurs(n-1,k-1)+ rekurs(n-1,k);
   }

}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int spalte = atoi(argv[1]);
    int zeile= atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("%d,%d",zahlen,rekurs(spalte,zeile));
    return 0;
}



#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int rekurs(int n, int k)
{ int ergebnis;
  if((k==0)||(n==0)||(n==k))
    {
        ergebnis = 1;
    }

    else{ 
      return ergebnis = rekurs(n-1,k-1)+ rekurs(n-1,k);
   }

}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int spalte = atoi(argv[1]);
    int zeile= atoi(argv[2]);
    printf("%d,%d",zahlen,rekurs(spalte,zeile));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your second code does not have `return` if the `if` condition is true. Assigning `ergebnis` in the `else` case is also pointless.

Comment: Remember that local variables are local for the current call only. In the second variant, each time you call `rekurs` a brand new `ergebnis` variable will created for that call and for that call only. When the function returns the variable reaches the end of its life-time and it ceases to exist and the value in it is lost.

Comment: ALWAYS enable your compiler's warnings. (For gcc, I use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Werror`.) It would have caught your error.

Answer (score 3):

The second recursive function returns nothing if the expression in the if statement evaluates to true

```
int rekurs(int n, int k)
{ int ergebnis;
  if((k==0)||(n==0)||(n==k))
    {
        ergebnis = 1;
    }

    else{ 
      return ergebnis = rekurs(n-1,k-1)+ rekurs(n-1,k);
   }

}
```

At least you need to write

```
int rekurs(int n, int k)
{ int ergebnis;
  if((k==0)||(n==0)||(n==k))
    {
        ergebnis = 1;
        return ergebnis;
    }

    else{ 
      return ergebnis = rekurs(n-1,k-1)+ rekurs(n-1,k);
   }

}
```

though using the variable `ergebnis` is redundant.

Also it seems the arguments of the functions must be non-negative values but the functions do not take this into account.

So it will be better to declare the function like

```
unsigned long long int rekurs( unsigned int n, unsigned int k )
{   
    if( ( k == 0 ) || ( n == 0 ) || ( n == k ) )
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    { 
      return rekurs( n - 1, k - 1 ) + rekurs( n - 1, k );
    }
}
```